# Is it ok to use "kill" as a standard-way to end processes?

Tags: linux, kill

I want to play a video using vlc in a loop until an operation is finished. My thoughts would be to do something like this:

```
vlc -f --loop loopvideo.mpg
[do some other stuff]
if (finished) 
  killall vlc
fi
```

coming from windows originally I still feel that killing a process is something bad you only do when something crashed. Is there a "cleaner" approach on *Nix systems than the "kill"-command or is this just fine?

Comment: In case of running in an infinite loop, I can't see any other legit way of stopping the process from running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kill` is fine, by default it should send a signal to the process to ask it to terminate. You can be sure of this by using `killall -s TERM vlc` if you like. The process should intercept the signal and close itself down gracefully.

Truly killing a process you would need to send a `KILL` rather than `TERM`. That signal is sent to the operating system rather than the process, so the O/S will actually stop the process without waiting for the process to clean up. You may have seen this command in its shorter form of `kill -9 <pid>` where `-9` = `-KILL`

Comment: SIGKILL is sent to the process, just like any other signal.  The only difference is that the process cannot handle SIGKILL, so you are guaranteed to get the default response (termination) and you give the process no chance to clean up any resources that it might still be using.